# Solve for a definite integral for each element within an array that is defined by a function in Python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, scipy, numerical-integration

I am attempting to integrate the values of an array. The Array used within the function is "H" and limits of integration for the integral are "surf" and "base". The values are read in from a .txt file. 'def flow_pramB(z)' defines the function to be integrated and 'def integrand(a,b)' performs the integral. Then I would like to call the function 'integrand' to produce a new array of individual values that have been integrated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

datafile = np.genfromtxt(" filename/flow_line_num9.txt",delimiter='\t',skiprows=1, dtype=float)

#The first four parameters are all arrays of numbers 
ptID = datafile[:,0] 
surf = datafile[:,9] #m
base = datafile[:,10] #m
H = surf - base #m

Bo = 2.207 #Pa yr^1/3
Ct = .16612 #K^k
Tr = 273.39 #K
k = 1.17
Ts = -19.0 #celsius
Tb = -2.0 #celsius

@np.vectorize
def integrand(a,b):
    def flow_pramB(z):
        temp = []
        for i in range(0,len(ptID)):
            tempA = ((Ts-Tb)*pow((z/H[i]),.333333))+Tb
            temp.append(tempA)
        B = []
        for i in range(0,len(ptID)):
            Bpram = (Bo*np.exp((3155/temp[i]) - (Ct/(pow((Tr-temp[i]),k)))))
            B.append(Bpram)
        return B
    return integrate.quad(flow_pramB, a, b)

B = integrand(surf, base)
```

This code is simply one example of many many tries to get this to work. A solution or just letting me know that I need to try other modules to get this to work would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what's the problem with this code? Is is working/not working, too slow etc? Also could you provide a link to `flow_line_num9.txt`, as otherwise it's hard to tell what's happening otherwise. The code looks good, you just need to vectorized a bit the `flow_pramB` to use numpy arrays instead of loops (if possible), as otherwise this will be very slow when called by `quad`.

Comment: This is a link to "flow_line_num9.txt" https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2L-Ia8P-GX6U1p2VTJCS0x3QTQ/view?usp=sharing Please let me know if it doesn't work. 

The program doesn't work. It seems that it's failing in the last loop when I call "integrand". When I try to run it, I get an error message of "error: Supplied function does not return a valid float"

Answer (score 0):

The function `flow_pramB` is incorrectly defined. It should take a float and return a float, not a list as it does now. For instance, here is a possible approach (note that we use numpy arrays instead of for loops),

```
def flow_pramB(z):
    temp = ((Ts-Tb)*pow((z/H[:]),.333333))+Tb
    B = (Bo*np.exp((3155/temp[:]) - (Ct/(pow((Tr-temp[:]),k)))))
    return B.sum() # suming all the elements of B (probably not the right thing to do)

@np.vectorize
def integrand(a,b):
    return integrate.quad(flow_pramB, a, b)

B = integrand(surf, base)
```

this runs, but produces some `NaNs` and warning because `flow_param` does not produce the correct results (as I'm not sure what it should produce). Still this gives you an idea, of how to make this work,

1. Verify that `flow_paramB` takes a float and returns the correct float  result.
2. Check that `integrate.quad(flow_paramB, a_float, b_float)` runs and produces the correct results.
3. Then wrap it with the `np.vecorize` decorator as you did.

Comment: Cheers for all your help! It looks like right now that flow_pramB is only returning a single value, am I correct in thinking that? If so, is it possible to have the function (flow_pramB) create an array of mathematical functions that have one undefined variable where then each element of the array will be separately integrated?